# Make API handler wrapper to reduce repetition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, endpoint

Right now to call a private endpoint I need to copy this code to each component. Which is messy, unsustainable, and error-prone. How would I wrap this behavior in a function call and put it where I want utilities to go? So I could `import { ApiUtil } from ..` and `ApiUtil.post('/user', user)`

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
import { useAuth0 } from '../../../react-auth0-spa'; 
    const authContext = useAuth0();
    const {
        getTokenSilently
    } = authContext; 
    const token = await getTokenSilently(); 
    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
           Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        url: '/user',
        data: user,
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a instance of `axios` and can be reused in each component

```
import axios from 'axios';

//token code sample

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
});

export default instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new file and export [an instance of `axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance)

```js
// ApiUtil.js
import axios from 'axios'; 
import { useAuth0 } from '../../../react-auth0-spa'; 

const authContext = useAuth0();
const { getTokenSilently } = authContext; 
const token = await getTokenSilently(); 

export default axios.create({
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
});
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```js
import ApiUtil from './ApiUtil';

// …
await ApiUtil.post('/user', { user });
```